# sql update command that is working in .asp file but not VBScript File

Tags: sql, asp.net, vbscript, adodb

I've got a sql update command that is working in .asp file but not VBScript File. Both were working before this code was added.

The error I get for the .vbs is:

`'Incorrect syntax near '='. Code 80040E14`

Here's the update Sub (connection string for ConnString and lngProductID value are already set):

```
Private Sub MakeProductUnavailable()
Dim myConn 
Dim myCommand 
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" ) 
    myConn.Open ConnString
    Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
    myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Product SET Product.Availability='N' WHERE Product.ProductID= " & lngProductID
    myCommand.Execute
    myConn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show how and where you have declared `lngProductID` and `myConn`?

Comment: Also, where they are set may help

Comment: I've got it working. In case anyone else runs into this issue, what worked for me was adding ' ' around lngProductID (even though it is an integer). Here's my updated sql:          
    myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Product SET Product.Availability='N' WHERE Product.ProductID='" & lngProductID & "'"